# iMac doesn't start, all i see is colored lines and then checkered lines on a white background

Tags: imac, screen, performance, macos, gpu

I have iMac 2010 which is out of warranty. I recently came up to the computer and it was sleeping and was not waking up. I held the powered button for a while, so it turned off. Then I pressed it again. The iMac turned on, but I saw colored lines on the white background with apple logo and activity indicator spinning. It was spinning for a bit then the screen changed to checkered color lines and white background, and it froze that way. I turned on my TV that the iMac is connected to and all I see there is white screen. I tried <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and it did restart, but same thing happened. I also tried plugging out all the cables, including power. Waiting for few minutes and plugging them back in, but that didn't help. What else can i try? Do you think the monitor is dead or the video card? Hopefully not the hard drive. Here are the screen shots of what happens:

[image: Loading Screen]

[image: Frozen Screen]

---

Update.
I am trying to do as little as possible, not to loose the data. I don't have much backed up.

I found the diagnostic CD and was able to run it. I ran the quick test and it found no issues. Now I am running the extended test. Would the extended test detect bad video card? I tried to start the iMac in Safe Mode with the same result. What are my choices, if it is the video card? To change it I would probably have to replace the whole motherboard, and Apple will charge I am sure over $300 if not more. Is there a way to boot from a flash drive to let's say Ubuntu and access the hard drive?

Here is the screen shot from that Diagnostic screen:

[image: Diagnostics Screen]

Comment: The best way to narrow down the problem is to plug in external monitor to see what is the problem. And to start in SAFE mode to eliminate drivers conflict.

Comment: I would suggest FireWire Target mode to save the data. In order to do that you'll need a another mac and a FireWire Cable. In FW target mode, your iMac will be seen as a FireWire Drive by the other Mac.

Comment: Would that work even though i can't boot into the desktop.  I only have the macbook pro that doesn't have firewire. Do i have any other options?  Is there a way to turning off the iMac screen and use the tv as primary through the display port?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to have an OS for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I went to the apple store and they said it is the video card and $200 to fix it.  I decided to let them fix it.  Hopefully they will not touch the hard drive and i am not going to loose any data.  I would think there is no reason for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you show us here are typical symptoms of a dead video card.

Comment: → Yan: stop experimenting with your iMac and cables, if you don't want to lose your data. Just run Apple Hardware Test: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509. If your video card is dead, this might be clearly visible from the start of the test, but you won't risk to damage anything else.

Comment: I posted an update to the question.  How would i see if the video card is dead?  Is it the lines or is it possibly the monitor is dying.  My guess because i am not getting the desktop most likely is the video card.  Thanks!