# Is there a way to boot on iMac from usb using a different OS and access osx files to back them up

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup

I am having issues starting up my iMac.  I would like to know if i create a bootable usb with Ubuntu or any other OS, would i be able to boot with it and access the OSX drive? I able to do this in windows with mini windows xp but never done it on mac.

==

The issue on my mac is related to the graphics card which prevents me from starting the mac.  Here is the question explaining the problem
[iMac doesn't start, all i see is colored lines and then checkered lines on a white background](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98677/imac-doesnt-start-all-i-see-is-colored-lines-and-then-checkered-lines-on-a-whi)

Comment: [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key) does not provide any solution, and for most other operating systems, you would need to configure something in OS X first. Yan, if it is a dead video card, then it does not matter what operating system you have, it will still most likely have issues. Therefore, as another post indicated on your other question, you will need another Mac and a FireWire cable to see if you can backup any data. You can't use an external monitor because your Mac doesn't start up.

Comment: I read that i can use ubuntu liveCD.  Is that easier and supported? I have a cd drive in the iMac so i can go either way.  It is just easier for me right now to create a flash drive vs cd.

Comment: I linked you to a [Ubuntu ISO for Mac](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64+mac.iso). You can try it, but if the video card is dead, then you still won't see anything.

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping to see ubuntu with lines and access the osx hard drive to copy the files.  I do see the diagnostic screen.  I guess it might be different.  Do you know if i do boot in ubuntu is it easy to access the osx hard drive?

Comment: It should be as simple as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103719/dual-boot-access-mac-os-hd-folders-from-ubuntu)- run `gksudo nautilus` in the Ubuntu Terminal (Dash => Search for Terminal). It will open up a "Finder" window with root privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went to the apple store and they said it is the video card and $200 to fix it. I decided to let them fix it. Hopefully they will not touch the hard drive and i am not going to loose any data. I would think there is no reason for that.